# How to see har output using selenium web driver and browser mob

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to do performance testing using browsermob proxy and webdriver with below code. I was able to setup everything and run sample test case. But how to get har output and view HAR viewer to analyse the results?

```
ProxyServer server = new ProxyServer(9090);
server.start();
Proxy proxy = server.seleniumProxy();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("webdriver");

WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(profile);            
profile.setProxyPreferences(proxy);
server.newHar("google.com");
driver.get("http://google.com");            
Har har = server.getHar();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am exploring Browsermob as well.  I think once u have the har, you can use the har.writeTo function to write to a file.  Then use a HAR viewer (http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/) to view the file.
http://code.google.com/p/harviewer/.

Comment: niharika_neo, thanks a lot for your response. Is my above code is correct? When i try to write to file for above code i just get output as "org.browsermob.core.har.Har@bdc9b3" and when i paste this in har viewer nothing i'm seeing. can you share sample script for capturing har with browsermob and webdriver?

Comment: Har har = server.getHar();
try {
har.writeTo(new File("c:\\test1.har"));
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();}

Answer (score 0):

After getting the `Har` object, you need to write it to a file. For example:

```
Har har = server.getHar();
try
{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("mycapture.har");
    har.writeTo(fos);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After this runs, you'll have a file named `mycapture.har` in the current working directory, and you can open it with a text editor. The file format is JSON. As niharika_neo noted, you can then upload the .har file to an online .har viewer.